# Does the oven door need to be toughened glass?

Tags: equipment, oven, glass

The glass door of my oven toaster and grill has broken. Can I use a thick glass (not toughened/tempered) in its place?

Comment: I guess the best option for you is to contact the brand/company of the oven and ask about the specifications of it.

Comment: This would be a better question for [diy.se], and would be more likely to get helpful answers there. If you want, you can ask a mod to move it there for you (click the "flag" link and select "other").

Answer (score 5):

You can't use just any sheet of thick glass for your oven door. Glass for your oven has to be tempered to resist high temperatures. Untempered glass will likely crack pretty quickly with regular use. Moreover, an oven door usually made of glass which breaks into "rough pebbles" rather than sharp shards if it breaks, to decrease the risk of injuries if the glass does crack. If you replace it with a regular thick glass pane you run the risk of (worst case scenario) very sharp, very hot shards of glass exploding all over your kitchen one day.

Like @M.K. stated in the comments, your best bet is to contact the company and ask about replacements, or a reputable company that repairs appliances. They can easily secure an appropriate piece of tempered glass to replace the broken one.

Comment: opening with 'yes' or 'no' is a problem for this question, as the question in the title is the opposite of what the body of the question ends with.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say, "yes", there is a reason that oven glass needs to be able to stand up to the heat. Even for a toaster oven. Safety. [What Kind of Glass is Used in Oven Doors](https://www.hunker.com/12000199/what-kind-of-glass-is-used-in-oven-doors)

The [online order/quote for tempered glass](https://www.crystalglassny.com/Store/Glass-Products-Info) I pulled up, guessing a 8"x12" sheet, quoted at $60 (plus taxes/shipping).  Then you have to take into consideration: the glass for your specific toaster oven might have (pre-drilled) holes for a handle to be screwed on, or adjustments for the bolts that fit it so that it swings open.  Perhaps you could get a replacement part by contacting the manufacturer (if the appliance isn't too old).

But it might not be worth your while to go through all that trouble. Check local discount shops (or even garage sales). I bet you could replace or upgrade the appliance for less money and aggrivation that fixing it would cause.

Comment: opening with 'yes' or 'no' is a problem for this question, as the question in the title is the opposite of what the body of the question ends with.

Comment: I can't say, "yes, but.... you might consider a different option"?

Answer (score 1):

If you use glass at all, it should be indeed special glass made to withstand the high temperatures.

However, there is no reason to use a glass door for your oven. If you need a cheap repair, you can make a door out of any other material that is sufficiently food safe and can withstand the temperature. A sheet of steel will work, and can be shaped as needed.

This assumes that you really have a pure toaster oven. If your oven has a microwave function, do not try to replace the door with random materials, send it in for servicing.

Comment: I would add that most full-size ovens have at least an air-gap between panes of glass in the window to prevent the glass getting blisteringly hot while cooking, and to contain some of the heat better. Replacing with metal might run more risk of having a high outside temperature that could burn if approached without suitable caution. As I am very sure you also know - you would also need to open the door more regularly to check on cooking items - affecting the cooking process.